# How to plot multiple line graphs by weekly in python

Tags: python, plot, linegraph

if I have data in <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> as the following example
[image]

So, I try to plot multiple line graphs in the same axis by separating them by weeknumber and named the axis with numberofday and QTyValue on x-axis and y-axis, representively. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is little unclear. I hope this answers your question. In case I have missed anything then, please let me know.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'Date_M':['2008-02-10', '2008-02-11', '2008-02-12', '2008-02-13','2008-02-14','2008-02-15'],
        'QTyValue': [0.6, 0.7, 0.6, 0.9, 0.5,0.6],
        'weeknumber':[7,7,8,8,9,9],
        'numberofday':[0,1,2,3,4,5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=None) 
fig = plt.figure()
for i in df['weeknumber'].unique():
  tmp = df[df['weeknumber'] ==i]
  plt.plot(tmp['numberofday'],tmp['QTyValue'])
plt.xlabel('numberofday')
plt.ylabel('QTyValue')
plt.title('Plot for each weeknumber in dataframe')
plt.legend(df['weeknumber'].unique())
plt.show()
```

This produces Following
[image]

Comment: I wrote this code for a random DataFrame. You can feed your DataFrame in df Variable directly.

Comment: Thank you vary much sir. It 's very helpful explanation for me.

Comment: Happy to help you Sir!!